# How to configure jenkins run on port 80 use docker?

Tags: docker, jenkins

i use below command , but it doesn't work, we must use `--ip` to pass ip to pass given ip to docker

`docker run -p 80:80080 --ip xx.xx.xx.xx jenkins`

Comment: Try to Follow this this link you can get the solution 


  [1]: https://engineering.riotgames.com/news/putting-jenkins-docker-container

Answer (score 9, accepted):

finnally i have resloved with add an environment parameter with docker command
`-e JENKINS_OPTS="--httpPort=80"`

Comment: I think using  `docker run -p 80:8080` is just fine

Comment: This *would* be the correct way, but the newer official jenkins/jenkins image runs its container contents as non-root, so it won't allow for a privileged port.  You could configure your docker server to allow non-privileged ports, but the most direct way would be to run a proxy container such as Nginx Proxy Manager and point it to your Jenkins container.

Comment: @FredDrake you are right, also need run as root  to listen port <= 1024, (default run as user jenkis)

Answer (score 3):

```
docker run -p 80:8080 -d jenkins/jenkins:latest
```

Comment: Would you like to augment your code-only answer with some explanation?

Answer (score 0):

```
docker run --name jenkinsci -p 8081:8080 jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

If 8080 is already in use, you can use 8081 but forward it to 8080, as jenkins starts on 8080

```
-p 8081:8080
```